# Make dynamic dropdown field required in Wordpress contact 7

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

So I have a dynamic dropdown in my WPCF7. The plugin querys the database for the published available free trial classes and puts these in the dropdown. Now I would like to know how I can make it a required field, so when form validation happens upon submit it checks if this field has been selected or not. (and displays the label that it's required)

I have this shortcode in my Contact form 7:

```
[select_free_trial]
```

Then in my functions.php of Wordpress I added this function and action:

```
add_action('wpcf7_init', 'add_cf7_free_trial');

function add_cf7_free_trial() {
    wpcf7_add_shortcode('select_free_trial', 'select_free_trial'); }

function select_free_trial() {
    $form = 'Free trial';

    include('/home/pureseat/BETANGOCRM/include/db.php');
    $sql= "SELECT CRM_PRODUCTS.ID, CRM_PRODUCTS.PRODUCTS_NAME, CRM_PRODUCTS.PRODUCTS_TIMING,CRM_PRODUCTS.PRODUCTS_DATES, CRM_LOCATIONS.LOCATIONS_CITY,CRM_LOCATIONS.LOCATIONS_CITY_FR, CRM_LOCATIONS.LOCATIONS_CITY_NL FROM CRM_PRODUCTS JOIN CRM_LOCATIONS ON CRM_PRODUCTS.LOCATIONS_ID=CRM_LOCATIONS.LOCATIONS_ID WHERE CRM_PRODUCTS.PRODUCTS_PUBLISHONWEBSITE=1 AND CRM_PRODUCTS.PRODUCTS_TYPE='FREE_TRIAL' order by CRM_PRODUCTS.PRODUCTS_DATES";
    $result = mysqli_query($coni,$sql);
    echo '<p><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap PRODUCTS_ID"><label> Please select *<select name="color" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-select wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">';
    echo '<option value=""></option>';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        printf('<option value="%s">%s</option>', $row['ID'], $row['PRODUCTS_NAME']);
    }
    echo '</select></label></span></p>';

    $custom_tag = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $custom_tag; }
```

I have already added this to the select field tag:

```
class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-select wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true"
```

But this does not result in a validation of the field.
I think I should probably add it to the javascript/jquery validation, but I'm kind of new to Wordpress so I don't know where to do this.

Or is there a better way to populate my dropdown? I've found also some information here https://xnau.com/populate-a-form-dropdown-from-the-database/ that would add a hook to the select field rather then a shortcode.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add select field name also in the parent span tag. Use below the code.

```
add_action('wpcf7_init', 'add_cf7_free_trial');

function add_cf7_free_trial() {
    wpcf7_add_shortcode('select_free_trial', 'select_free_trial'); }

function select_free_trial() {
    $form = 'Free trial';

    include('/home/pureseat/BETANGOCRM/include/db.php');
    $sql= "SELECT CRM_PRODUCTS.ID, CRM_PRODUCTS.PRODUCTS_NAME, CRM_PRODUCTS.PRODUCTS_TIMING,CRM_PRODUCTS.PRODUCTS_DATES, CRM_LOCATIONS.LOCATIONS_CITY,CRM_LOCATIONS.LOCATIONS_CITY_FR, CRM_LOCATIONS.LOCATIONS_CITY_NL FROM CRM_PRODUCTS JOIN CRM_LOCATIONS ON CRM_PRODUCTS.LOCATIONS_ID=CRM_LOCATIONS.LOCATIONS_ID WHERE CRM_PRODUCTS.PRODUCTS_PUBLISHONWEBSITE=1 AND CRM_PRODUCTS.PRODUCTS_TYPE='FREE_TRIAL' order by CRM_PRODUCTS.PRODUCTS_DATES";
    $result = mysqli_query($coni,$sql);
    echo '<p><label> Please select *<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap PRODUCTS_ID color"><select name="color" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-select wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">';
    echo '<option value=""></option>';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        printf('<option value="%s">%s</option>', $row['ID'], $row['PRODUCTS_NAME']);
    }
    echo '</select></span></label></p>';

    $custom_tag = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $custom_tag; }
```

Comment: thanks for answering.. that does not seem to do anything either. Here's my test page: https://www.be-tango.com/test-php.html

Comment: If I change the name of my select dropdown to another one that exists in the form it does give me the required message. But when I use a diffent name (color in this case) it does not work... it can't be that I need to hard code all the custom fields somewhere in javascript of validation?